# Chrome Extension background script open webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can a Chrome extension background script open a webpage in a new tab, if a specific URL is not already open?

Comment: Sure, use chrome.tabs.query and then chrome.tabs.create if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Copy that text into an answer so I can accept that as the answer!